# Filtration of norm-one elements of quaternion algebra over local field with respect to an involution

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, non-archimedean-fields, involutions, filtrations

Let $K$ be a local non-archimedean field, with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, uniformizing element $\varpi_K$, and residue field $\mathcal{O}_K/\varpi_K\mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{F}_q$. For simplicity, assume the residue characteristic $p \neq 2$.

Let $D$ be a quaternion algebra over $K$, with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_D$, uniformizing element $\varpi_D$, and residue field $\mathcal{O}_D/\varpi_D\mathcal{O}_D \cong \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.

Let $L/K$ be quadratic unramified extension, with $L = K[u]$ for some $u \in L$. Then $L$ is a splitting field of $D$, and we can write elements of $d \in D$ as $$d = k_1 + k_2u + k_3 \varpi_D + k_4u\varpi_D$$

for some $k_i \in K$. Furthermore, we have the relation $u \varpi_D = -\varpi_D u$, and a uniformizer $\varpi_K$ of $K$ can be chosen so that $\varpi_D^2 = \varpi_K$.

Let $\sigma$ be an involution of $D$ of 1st kind and 1st type -- meaning the restriction of $\sigma$ to $K$ is trivial, and the fixed space of $\sigma$ is dimension $3$ over $K$.

For simplicity, let's take $$\sigma(d) = \sigma(k_1 + k_2u + k_3 \varpi_D + k_4u\varpi_D) = k_1 - k_2u + k_3 \varpi_D + k_4u\varpi_D.$$

$\\\\$
$\\\\$

Let $T = \{ d \in D^\times \text{ : } \sigma(d) \cdot d=1 \}$ -- a special orthogonal group in one variable with respect to the $\sigma$-quadratic form $q(d) = \sigma(d) \cdot d$.

Fix a valuation $\text{val}$ on $K$ such that $\text{val}(K^\times) = \mathbb{Z}$ -- extending this valuation to $D$ gives $\text{val}(D^\times) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the filtration groups $$T_0 = \{ d \in \mathcal{O}_D^\times \text{ : } \text{val}(d) \geq 0\},$$

$$T_r = \{ d \in \mathcal{O}_D^\times \text{ : } \text{val}(d-1) \geq r \}, \text { for any $r \geq 0$ }.$$

Does anyone know how to compute the quotients $T_r/T_{r + \frac{1}{2}}$? Or does anyone have a suggestion for a resource? Based on some work I've done on some work I started and some reading I've done on quaternionic unitary groups, trying to work out their Moy-Prasad filtration groups, I have a small hunch that $T_0/T_{\frac{1}{2}} \cong \{\pm 1\}$, and $T_r/T_{r + \frac{1}{2}} \cong \mathbb{F}_q.$
$\\\\$
$\\\\$

If it's any help, using the $d$ and $\sigma$ from above, $$\sigma(d)d = k_1^2 - k_2^2u^2 + k_3^2\varpi_K - k_4^2u^2\varpi_K + 2(k_1k_3 - k_3k_4)\varpi_D + 2(k_1k_4-k_2k_3)u\varpi_D.$$

If we are concerned about $1 = \sigma(d)d$. Then, $$1 = k_1^2 - k_2^2u^2 + k_3^2\varpi_K - k_4^2u^2\varpi_K,$$
$$0 = k_1k_3 - k_3k_4,$$
$$0 = k_1k_4-k_2k_3.$$

I don't know if there is some (quasi) anisotropicity at play with the first equation; if there is, I suppose that, and the other two equations can help cut down dimensions of quotients of the filtration.